# Suppose I define a function f(x) in python inside which there is a conditon checking the value

Tags: python, iteration

... of x. I assume x to be an int (or not to be list). Now I generate a list of value of x and then to get corresponding f(x), I apply (using numpy) f(x), which for me implies that each element in y is f(xi) but python is interpretting it as argument x for f(x). Now since it contains a condition, it reports an error (because conditions like <,>,= only is meaningful to int..).

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    if x == 0:
       return 0
    if x == 1:
       return 1

    return f(x-1) + f(x-2)

x = np.linspace(1,100,100)
y = np.array(f(x))
print (x)
print (y)
```

Comment: Even after you get the syntax correct you wouldn't be able to finish evaluating `y` anytime in the next billion years or so since your recursive Fibonnaci function involves an infeasibly large number of function calls long before you get to `n` = 100

Comment: probably you are right but then can you explain it to me how someone got this graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: It is trivially easy to write non-recursive Fibonacci (or factorial) functions

Comment: For that matter, start with `fibs = [0,1]` then type `for i in range(1,100): fibs.append(fibs[i-1]+fibs[i])` and in a fraction of a second you have the list of the first 100 Fibonacci numbers. No need for anything like numpy

Comment: it's trivial to write recursive one too, you just have to use cache, say dict. for each x check is cached, if it is return it, else cache f(x).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply `f` on each elem of np collection...

```
xs = np.linspace(1,100,100)
ys = np.array(map(f, xs))
```

**UPDATE**

faster `f`

```
cache = {}

def f(x):
    if not cache.has_key(x):
        cache[x] = x if x == 0 or x == 1 else f(x-1) + f(x-2)
    return cache[x]

print f(8)  # 21
print cache # {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 5, 6: 8, 7: 13, 8: 21}
```

Comment: which python version you have? i've tested this on `2.7.6` and it works. also, please test it on smaller input, say `xs = np.linspace(1,5,5)`